# Android app crashes upon attempt to switch to a different Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am running into an issue in my app. When my game ends (when `life == 0`) I am attempting to switch to a game over screen by using a different activity. When the game ends, the app simply crashes. I have included the XML for the activity I am trying to switch from as well as indicating where the app crashes. If anyone could help out, that would be great! Thanks.

activity_game.XML:

[image]

`SurfaceView` I am trying to switch from once game ends:

```
public class SVGameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
        private SurfaceHolder holder;
    Thread thread = null;
    volatile boolean running = false;
    static final long FPS = 30;
    private Sprite sprite;
    private long lastClick;

    private Bitmap ball, gameOver;
    //private int x = 200, y = 200;
    private int scorePosX = 100;
    private int scorePosY = 100;
    private int countScore = 0;
    private int life = 1;

    public SVGameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        thread = new Thread(this);
        holder = getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                boolean retry = true;
                running = false;
                while (retry) {
                    try {
                        thread.join();
                        retry = false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                running = true;
                thread.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                                       int width, int height) {
            }
        });

        ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball2);
        gameOver = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.endscreen);
        sprite = new Sprite(this, ball);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
        long startTime;
        long sleepTime;

        while (running) {
            Canvas c = null;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            try {
                c = getHolder().lockCanvas();
                synchronized (getHolder()) {
                    update();
                    draw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                if (c != null) {
                    getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
            sleepTime = ticksPS-(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            try {
                if (sleepTime > 0)
                    thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                else
                    thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {}

        }
    }

    private void update(){
        sprite.update();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setTextSize(48);
        canvas.drawText("Score: " + countScore, scorePosX, scorePosY, paint);
        canvas.drawText("Lives: " + life, 500, 100, paint);
        sprite.onDraw(canvas);

        //Crashes here
        if(life == 0) {
            getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), SVGameOver.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if(System.currentTimeMillis()-lastClick > 300){
            lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        synchronized (getHolder()){
            if(sprite.isHit(event.getX(), event.getY())){
                countScore += 1;
                sprite.increase();
            }else{
                life --;
            }
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

Activity I am trying to reach once the game ends:

```
public class SVGameOver extends Activity {

    private Bitmap gameOverScreen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        gameOverScreen = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.endscreen);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawBitmap(gameOverScreen, 0,0,null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you update your logcat of crash?

Comment: @RohitSharma I am using Android Studio. I've indicated where the crash occurs at.

Comment: Can you please tell what exception is causing the crash?

Comment: @RohitSharma android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.welcome.assignment2/com.example.welcome.assignment2.SVGameOver}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 1):

I think logcat is asking you the right question: "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml" ?

If you think you did it, It's highly probable you did it in a wrong way, most of the times that you think you added an Activity to the manifest but you are receiving this kind of crash, 99,9% of the time you declared it with a wrong namespace

Answer (score 0):

Declare SVGameOver activity in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.welcome.assignment2.SVGameOver">
    ...
</activity>
```